# Conditional function plotting in matplotlib

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, plot, conditional-statements

My aim is to plot a function with two variable t and x.
we assign 0 to x if 0

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
t=np.linspace(0,5,100)
def x(i):
    if i <= 1:
        j = 1
    else :
        j = 0
    return j
y = 8*x(t)-4*x(t/2)-3*x(t*8)

plt.plot(t,y)
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.show()
```

it return an error :

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what do you want to do with that code? take a look `t` is a np.array then you use it as a single number the element wise operator didn’t work in that case maybe you prefer using a loop like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
t=np.linspace(0,5,100)
def x(i):
    if i <= 1:
        j = 1
    else :
        j = 0
    return j
y = []
for i in t:
    y.append(8*x(i)-4*x(i/2)-3*x(i*8))

# or using list comprehensions
y = [8*x(i)-4*x(i/2)-3*x(i*8) for i in t]

plt.plot(t,y)
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use classical `if` on numpy arrays, at least not in the pointwise sense. That is not a problem because you can just do boolean operations on the array:

```
def x(i):
    j = (i<=1)*1.
    return j
```

Answer (score 3):

Your function `x` can't handle array inputs as it stands (because of the comparison operations). You could create a temporary array in this function to set the values as appropriate:

```
def x(t):
    tmp = np.zeros_like(t)    
    tmp[t <= 1] = 1
    return tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

you could loop over the values in `t` when assigning `y`, since your function `x` only takes one number as its argument. Try this:

```
y = np.array([8*x(tt)-4*x(tt/2)-3*x(tt*8) for tt in t])

print y

array([ 1,  1,  1,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,
        4,  4,  4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4,
       -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0])
```

The vectorised answers (e.g. by @Christoph and @xnx) are a better way to do this, though